# Link being hidden by JS

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, hidden

I'm using a the AnimatedContentMenu tutorial from tympanus, and trying to integrate links into the drop down menus.

However, when adding an `<a>` to the `li` the text disappears and I cant work out why.

The site is http://designandintention.com/ and the code in question is

```
    <a href="images/NYSkyline.jpg">Banners</a>
    <div class="ac_subitem">
    <span class="ac_close"></span>
    <h2>Banners</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>By using various creative tools such as Adobe's Photoshop and Illustrator, I have designed various banners that have been displayed in many confrence centers and halls around the UK.</li>
    <li><a class="aclink" href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your style.css, you've got a line that look like

```
.ac_menu > ul > li a {
....
  opacity: 0;
....
}
```

If you remove the opacity:0; it works.

Comment: Yeah that has worked around the problem, I should be able to work with it, thank you so much for responding so quickly.

Comment: I think because its using the JS for a transition from opacity to solid which is why I couldn't work it out.